# Simple desktop gadget won't save its data between runs

Tags: windows-7, windows-desktop-gadgets

I'm trying to write a very simple Windows 7 gadget, which is easy enough. But I can't get any of the data I'm saving with `System.Gadget.Settings.write/read` (`writeString`/`readString`) to persist between runs of the gadget. I know it can be done, because all the other Microsoft gadgets do it. I'm obviously missing something crucial, but can't see it.

This is a very simple cut down example:

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="MSThemeCompatible" CONTENT="yes" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=Unicode" />
<title>test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function save() {
            var e = document.getElementById("name");
            if (e && e.value) {
                System.Gadget.Settings.write("name", e.value);
                prompt("turnedout", System.Gadget.Settings.read("name"));
            }
        }

        function load() {
            var t = System.Gadget.Settings.read("name");
            prompt("turnedout", t);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body scroll="no" unselectable="on" onload='load()'>
    <label for='name'>Name</label>
    <input id='name'>
    <input type="button" value='Save' onclick='save()' />
</body>
</html>
```

I've traced through the code and everything appears to go in the right places. What's missing?

Comment: Stop editing errors into your post!

Answer (score 0):

Gadgets don't work like desktop applications with regard to settings. The settings are per instance of a gadget. Close the instance and you lose the settings. There are other limitations as well. There's a good explanation at: http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/net/SettingsManagerforWindowsVistaSidebarGadgets.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Even I had the same issue, but when I moved the System.Gadget.Settings.write("name", e.value); to the html which is specified in the gadget.xml file, it wrote to the settings.ini file properly